# Values from xml in EXTJS

Tags: xml, extjs

I get a xml file with some data. I want to use some data to display in a displayfield and the rest in a grid. How can i do this?

This is the xml:

```
<blocked><report><sourceFile>log.1</sourceFile><date>11-10-2011</date><total>52996</total><parseIssues>279</parseIssues><categories><category>
```

So i need date, parseissues and total in three displayfields used in a panel. The categories are used in a grid. The categories are not a problem, i got them working but how do i display the other values outside the grid?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code block for following XML data.

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
  url: 'somefile.xml',
  reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
    record: 'element',
    fields: ['title', 'name']
  })
});
```

Here is an XML format that should work with the code.

```
<elements>
   <element>
      <title>sfdsf</title>
      <name>dfddfs</name>
   </element>
   <element>
      <title>bla</title>
      <name>rtz</name>
   </element>
   <element>
      <title>xsd</title>
      <name>awe</name>
   </element>
</elements>
```

For more detailed information please go to [this page](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?65859-Simple-XML-parsing-with-ExtJS) on Sencha forum.

Comment: Thanks Fatih,

I am allready using a store and that is working. I use the data in a grid but i want to display the sourceFile field in a displayfield and not sure how to do that